# Windows 10: Multiple remote users

Tags: remote-access

I am a statistics teacher.
I am setting up a powerful PC at home so my five students can remotely access the stats software on it.

I have looked at a few possible remote access possibilities, but none seem to meet the following simple requirements for less than $50 a month.

1. Each user logs in to their own account
2. They can upload files to their account
3. Multiple users can be logged in concurrently.

Can someone suggest the best way to achieve these requirements on a limited budget?

Comment: Do you know if the application supports multiple concurrent instances?  It sounds like you want a remote desktop alternative.  I'd maybe Google for Remote Desktop alternatives. TSPlus might be worth a look.

Comment: Google Remote Desktop doesn't seem to do a good job in authenticating remote users. I'll look into TS Plus

Comment: Consumer versions of Windows 10 don’t support concurrent multiple users sessions

Comment: what versions do support it then?

Comment: As mentioned, Windows workstation is not designed for this. Microsoft makes Windows Server for this scenario.

Comment: The easy way is to use the operating system's support for multiple users.  However, Windows 10 restricts this.  So you're bumping into a licensing restriction.  Either find some software that re-implements the concept of logging in, which Windows handles, or use Microsoft's implementation which won't be as cheap as you are asking (e.g., not using Windows 10).  This may sound disappointing; it is how Microsoft has made a lot of money.  Can be done for free with Unix software (possibly using Wine), although you may find that setup to be significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This is impossible with an Windows workstation edition OS.

A Windows workstation OS (such as Windows 10) has two accessible "interfaces":

1. **Console**, which is accessible via the physical machine's interface and via most remote access programs such as VNC, LogMeIn, etc.
2. **Remote Desktop** interface, which is accessible through the Windows RDP interface.

These two interfaces are the only consoles exposed by a workstation edition of Windows. The EULA (license agreement between a licensee of Windows and Microsoft) prohibits more than a single licensed user from accessing these interfaces at any one time. This is enforced by the fact access to one of the two consoles forces the other to disconnect.

### **Bottom line:** You cannot do this with a workstation edition of Windows.

In the Windows OS world, what you're trying to accomplish requires a Windows Server OS with the Remote Desktop Session Host role installed and the requisite RDSH Client Access Licenses (CALs). These are somewhat costly...unless you're eligible for Microsoft's Non-Profit (Charity) licensing program, which offers such software at <25% retail in some cases. Check with your Microsoft license provider for details.

Comment: your answer is perfectly valid and good. However, it is not technically impossible to do this on Windows workstation. I'm not sure if the hack still exists, but it did for Windows 7, and it allows multiple simultaneous RDP sessions. I believe it involves patching a .dll file. Forgot all about this until just a moment ago. I've never used it, but I've seen it in action - to my disgust. Lol.

Comment: @Appleoddity You're correct. I intentionally excluded modifications to the OS that violate the EULA.

Comment: I have the same question of the OP. Can you describe or link a reference that explains what can be done with Windows Server (e.g. Windows Server 2019)? I guess there's a third "interface" available, but how is it named?